# Awstats permission denied with Apache on Windows

Tags: apache, windows-7, statistics, xampp, awstats

I am trying to run **awstats** on windows 7 with apache from xammp tools. but i get this error, when i click on "update" from the website:

***Error: Couldn't open server log file "C:\Users\ekc\Documents\Projekte\16 Lasttests\Access Logs\s96ess5a1" : Permission denied 
Setup ('C:/xampp/cgi-bin/awstats.www.testmywebsite.com.conf' file, web server or permissions) may be wrong.
Check config file, permissions and AWStats documentation (in 'docs' directory).***

But if i set my ***LogFile=*** in **awstats.www.testmywebsite.com.conf** direkt to log file self instead of to the folder of log, it works! I mean, if i use ***..\Access Logs\s96ess5a1\2015-02-01*** instead of ***..\Access Logs\s96ess5a1***

I have set all of the permissions with right click on this folder for my user, to write and to change the folder.

What is the reason of that?